# How to load Ninject at startup with API

Tags: asp.net, ninject

Currently I load Ninject kernel when api controller is called, I can't find on Google how to do it on startup? Currently I have `IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(myBinding);` and `kernel.Get<Interace>();` but that's inside api controller how can I load it on startup?

Comment: Did you check [the documentation](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.WebApi/wiki)? Try implementing their code? What went wrong with your implementation? Can you post a [MCVE] showing your attempt at implementing it properly?

Comment: Nothing went wrong it works, I just can't find proper documentation on loading kernel at startup

Comment: I linked you to the documentation. You need to *read* the documentation.

Comment: Isn't that all for Mvc?..Never mind found it, thanks

Comment: It's for Web API. It says "Ninject.Web.WebApi" which is the integration library you use for making Ninject work with Web API.